# How to get the particular value of a key from a hashmap while iterating through it, in rust?

Tags: rust, serde

I am trying to iterate over a hashmap which I have extracted from a serde_json::value::Value

I want to check if the value of a particular key "type" is either "release" or "snapshot".

**I did this once in Nodejs, I am trying to replicate this in rust.**

Nodejs code for reference purpose:
[image: Nodejs code]

Json file which I am using:

https://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/game/version_manifest.json

Here's the piece of code relevant to the question (which I did so far)

```
requests::file_downloader::async_download_file("https://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/game/version_manifest.json", &version_json_dir).expect("Error fetching data!");

let f1 = fs::read_to_string(format!("{}/version_manifest.json", version_json_dir)).expect("Error opening file!");

let json_value: serde_json::value::Value = serde_json::from_str(f1.as_str())?;

for (key, value) in json_value["versions"].as_object().unwrap() {
        println!("{} => {}", key,value)
                
}
```

In another code file I tried this :

```
let mut h1: HashMap<String,String> = HashMap::new();

h1.insert("id".to_string(),"22w43a".to_string());
h1.insert("type".to_string(), "snapshot".to_string());


println!("{:#?}", h1.get_key_value("type").unwrap().1);
```

This returns "snapshot" as expected. But my problem is that the json file I am using is huge and I cannot find an effecient way to iterate over the extracted hashmap and implement the above logic.

Comment: I suspect it's not the iterating/indexing that's slow but the parsing of a huge json file.

Comment: speed is not an issue here. I just want to iterate over the hashmap and find the value for a specific key in each case.

Comment: Why do you need to iterate over a hashmap to find a value? Hashmaps are supposed to be an O(1) operation. What's wrong with getting the value by the key?

Comment: if you look at the json file properly, in the versions array this pattern is repeated :

{
      "id": "something",
      "type": "snapshot",
      "url": "something",
      "time": "something",
      "releaseTime": "something"
    },

So I want to iterate over this part and for every type whose value is "release", I want to print out the id.

Comment: @bruce_wayne224 And why doesn't a `for` loop work?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hard to say without a [mre], but are you looking for `json_value["versions"].as_object().unwrap().values().filter (|v| v.as_object().unwrap()["type"] == "release").map (|v| v.as_object().unwrap()["id"]).collect::<Vec<_>>()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it can be done using serde_json::Value, it is going to be a pain because you have to check manually everytime whethere a certain value exists, a better way and more rusty way to do it it is the following:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Version {
    id: String,
    url: String,
    #[serde(rename="type")]
    type_: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct MojangResponse {
    versions: Vec<Version>,
}

requests::file_downloader::async_download_file("https://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/game/version_manifest.json", &version_json_dir).expect("Error fetching data!");

let f1 = fs::read_to_string(format!("{}/version_manifest.json", version_json_dir)).expect("Error opening file!");

let json_value: MojangResponse  = serde_json::from_str(f1.as_str())?;

for version in json_value.versions.into_iter().filter(|it|&it.type_ == "release") {
    println!("{} => {}", version.id,version.url)
            
}
```

Notice I used `.into_iter()` and not `.iter()` which consumes the response but avoids using clone.

Comment: Yea I eventually followed this method. I will accept this answer though. Thanks